# Is it possible to use the same key name within different groups? (Reactive Forms)

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use the same key name within different groups?
(Reactive Forms)

So something like the following snippet. Does it work without any negative side effects?

```
new FormGroup({
  firstGroup: new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    secondName: new FormControl(),
  }),
  secondGroup: new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(),
    secondName: new FormControl(),
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You just did it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32006955)

Comment: How come? It precisely answers this very particular question *Is it possible to use the same key name within different groups? (Reactive Forms)*

Comment: You are right, it does answer the question. I guess the question is a bit low quality and answer sounds more of a chat, but it does answer the question. Sorry for the wrong review. It does bother me that sometimes questions aren't looked into more and they answer them selfs and no effort gets put into them.

Comment: This is why I have answered it and voted to close

Comment: Yea. I voted to close it also after you pointed to my review. Thanks

Comment: I was not sure if this example was working or would have any negative side effects. I also extended the question a bitt. Thank you guys.

Comment: I think that at the bottom level, Form is just a plain JS object (which you can access with `.getRawValue()`), so using duplicate field names on different levels is just fine